# Custom InstallAnywhere location for .com.zerog.registry.xml file on linux

Tags: linux, unix, installation, var, installanywhere

I'm running into an issue where I do not have write access to the /var directory on a UNIX environment, and InstallAnywhere doesn't provide me the option of writing the .com.zerog.registry.xml to any other location for a product installation.  Is there a parameter out there that allows for this file to be written to a different directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the IA docs:

> If logged in as root, the global registry is located in \var.
>
> If logged in as a user, it is located in the user’s home directory.

So, if you're running as root and can't write to `/var`, it sounds like a permissions problem with the `/var` directory, independent of IA. Check the permissions on `/var`.

If you're running as a non-root user, then the registry shouldn't be going to `/var`, but to `$HOME/.com.zerog.registry.xml` (FWIW, I just checked one of our test Linux boxes and found `.com.zerog.registry.xml` under both `/var` and under test-user `$HOME` directories. The docs appear to be correct).

I've also seen some very strange behavior if IA is low on space in $TMP. Make sure you have plenty of space there.

Also, have you considered running the installer with `sudo`, or the graphical equivalents `kdesudo` (KDE) and `gksu` (Gnome)? Those might get you where you want to go.

Comment: very helpful.  I didn't have permission to /var, but installing under a different username puts the xml file where you stated.  thanks!